# JavaFX 2d game engine: How to move camera as player moves?

Tags: javafx, game-engine, 2d-games

I am creating a 2d topdown game (with canvas size 720x480) where I want the camera to move once the player reaches a certain part of the screen. For example, once the player reaches 2/3 of the way to the right, the camera should then start scrolling to the right.

For reference, here is an image of the game world: [game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKBPU.png)

In my code, I have every object implementing a "genericObj" class, which has a position, velocity, and dimensions. So this is what I am thinking of doing once the player reaches 2/3 of the way to the right and is continuing to move to the right:

1. set the player's velocity to half the original
2. update every object's velocity with the negative of half the player's velocity (object.velocity -= player.velocity)
3. check if objects are within the view of the camera
4. display the objects that are within the view, disregard others

The reason for using half the player's velocity for both the new player velocity and the objects is that, in my code, the player movement sprite is only updated when the player is moving. Therefore, I need the player to be moving as opposed to setting the player velocity to 0 and the velocity of every object to negative player.velocity.

Is this a good way of "moving" the camera? What are some better methods of moving the camera? Also, would performance be an issue if I used this method of moving the camera (for example if I had 50+ objects)?

Comment: Maybe the [FXGL](https://github.com/AlmasB/FXGL) game library provides what you need?

Comment: You plan sounds fine and should work. Don't worry about performance yet. You are probably not even close to any limitations here. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil".